# How to fix language change shortcut in 17.10 unity?

Tags: language-support, input-language

`Super+Space` used to allow me to toggle between input sources (languages) in 17.04 and previous releases, but in 17.10 Unity it has no effect.

The shortcut is still the same in the settings window:

[image]

Comment: If you need something like *Alt+Shift* you should use GNOME Tweaks (`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`).

Comment: I just tried <Super>+<Space> on 17.10 with Unity, and it worked as usual for me.  One theory is that your `~/.config/dconf/user` file has been corrupted somehow. To test that, you can try to rename the file to e.g. `user.old` and relogin.

Comment: That was not it unfortunately: https://imgur.com/a/u8uIy